# Python - Display Data Block Image prop?

Tags: python, scripting, panel

In the Image tab there is the Image Data Block property. That's the part that i want to display. The problem is, it is part of a C template. And so i cannot simply grab this prop. layout.template_image simply displays the whole content of the panel. Not just this one prop.

```
class TEXTURE_PT_image(TextureTypePanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Image"
    tex_type = 'IMAGE'
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_RENDER', 'BLENDER_GAME'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        tex = context.texture

        layout.template_image(tex, "image", tex.image_user)
```

The tooltip gives a hint though about the Python code for the prop. But i can still not find a way to display this prop separately. I always end in errors. I fear i do it miserably wrong.

Is there even a way to access and display this prop from Python? And if so, how?

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is the prop search method http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=prop+search

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So the answer is, no, not directly. But am i able to make a prop that way that has the same functionality then?

Comment: Yes, instead of looking for the list of objects in the scene (bpy.data.objects or bpy.context.scene.objects), you'll be looking for images (bpy.data.images)